# Proper Coding Techniques in R

Tags: r, coding-style

I am writing an R code that has many different functions that eventually I will want to use all together on different data sets.

As I keep building functions it seems to be getting harder to keep track of everything in my script.

My question is, is it proper  R coding to break functions into separate R Scripts or should it all be in one massive script?

Thank you for your help. This is my first time trying to code something this large!

-B

Comment: Look into creating a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can store your functions in multiple R scripts.
If you need to call them, you can use `source()`.

For eg:
Say you have func1 , func2 saved in myfunc.R.

To call them,

```
source('myfunc.R')

#other codes

func1()
func2()
```

As to whether this approach is recommended, depends on your project requirements.

Alternatively, you can consider packaging them as recommended by Richard.